# Module configuration page with user groups

Tags: module, prestashop, registration

I'm completing a module that concerns the registration of new users.
Now, my module creates a table in the db that has an id field and an id_usergoup field.

On the configuration page, I would like to see the box with all the user groups available.
The user can select some and their id goes to write in my table. Similarly, in the box I have to see selected ones already chosen (if there are).

How can I make the box with user groups with HelperForm?
And take select the values already chosen and saved in my table?
I hope in your suggestion. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the array for the inputs, you can generate the customer group with this code:

```
array(
    'type' => 'group',
    'label' => $this->l('Customer group'),
    'name' => 'groupBox',
    'required' => true,
    'values' => Group::getGroups((int)$this->context->language->id),
    'hint' => $this->l('Customer group for which this tab will be available.'),
)
```

And you can get the selected values with: `Tools::getValue('groupBox');`

Regards!